# Hightcharts chart not resizing to fill space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, jquery-events

I'm having an issue about a highcharts chart not resizing itself automatically.

Being hidden (`display: none`) at page load because it is under a non-active tab, the chart only fills half of the available space when I open the corresponding tab.

It resizes itself automatically when I resize manually the window, but nothing happens when I trigger `resize` event on `$(window)` from jQuery script...

I have created a fiddle to reproduce the issue: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/xmc9j9p0/2/)

(On the fiddle the chart remains readable, but doesn't fill the whole available space)

Could someone help me out with that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your HTML/CSS to have a width & min-width will fix this issue.

```
<div id="chart10_18" style="display: none; width: 100%; min-width: 100%;" class="graph"></div>
```

[Your fiddle is updated here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmc9j9p0/3/)